# How to make svn client on linux mint?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using windows server 2003 as a SVN Server and i want to configure SVN client on Linux mint 14 64 bit.How to configure SVN client on linux mint?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Subversion on your Linux box? If so, you should be able to just point to the URL of your Windows server, and do a checkout.

If you don't have Subversion on your Linux box, you need to install it. Your Linux distro's package manager should have a release of Subversion you can use, and should be the first place to check.

If you cannot use your distro's Subversion package, you can download a Subversion client from the [Subversion Apache project](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html).

There's really not much to configuration you have to do for Subversion client to talk to a Subversion repository. You just need the URL of your Subversion server's repository. Do you know your Subversion repository URL?